# compatible pip version for python 3.3.1

Tags: python, django, pip, setuptools, easy-install

Brief overview on what I am trying to do

Step 1 - Python installed successfully- Version - Python 3.3.1

Step 2 - Either download easy_install or pip. I am going with pip.

Since pip doesn't have a windows installer. I have to download setuptools MS Windows installer via following link
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools#files

The latest version of pip available is 1.4

Step 3 - Install Django 1.5.1

Problem/Doubt - The latest version of setup tool available is for Python 2.7. Now I am wondering whether it is compatible with Python 3.3.1 or not. Even if I download setuptool 2.7, am I able to install Django through it? My final goal is to set-up Django framework on Python 3.3.1.

Any other alternatives are welcome. Apologies if the title of this question is somewhat misleading. If you think of a proper title, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

`setuptools` doesn't support python3, use [`distribute`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute). Everything else should be explained [here.](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html#requirements)

Comment: I am getting somewhat lost in here. Document for installing distribute says "Distribute is only released as a source distribution. It can be installed using pip, and can be done so with the source tarball, or by using the 'distribute_setup.py' script provided online." How do I install pip without distribute?

Comment: just download [`http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py`](http://python-distribute.org/distribute_setup.py) and execute `python distribute_setup.py`. Then do the same with [`https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py`](https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py). That should do it.

Comment: Seems like I am a complete noob here when it comes to execute python script. I am running the command on windows command prompt 
C:\Users\Dell>python distribute_setup.py and it gives me error can't open the file. No such file exist. I have already downloaded distribute_setup.py file on my system.
P.S -> I have already added the path to my python folder.

Comment: Ohh it was my stupid mistake...I was giving the wrong path name.